# Another question about asymptotic models in Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The array $(x_{i}^{k})_{i=1,k\in\mathbb{N}}^{\infty}$ of normalized $M$-basic sequences in a Banach space $X$ is itself called $M$-basic if, for every $k\leq i_{1}<i_{2}<\ldots$, the diagonal sequence $(x^{k}_{i_{k}})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is $M$-basic. If, in particular, there exists a normalized basic sequence $(v_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ in a Banach space $(V,\|\cdot\|_{V})$ and a sequence $\epsilon_{n}\downarrow 0$ of positive real numbers such that
\begin{equation*} \left\vert\left\Vert\sum_{k=1}^{N}\lambda_{k}x^{k}_{i_{k}}\right\Vert-\left\Vert\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_{i}v_{i}\right\Vert_{V}\right\vert<\epsilon_{N} \end{equation*}
for all $N\leq i_{1}<\ldots<i_{N}$ and for all $(\lambda_{i})_{i=1}^{N}\in[-1,1]^{N}$, then $(v_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is said to be an asymptotic model of $X$ generated by the array $(x^{k}_{i})_{i=1,k\in\mathbb{N}}^{\infty}$.

Asymptotic models were first introduced by Halbeisen and Odell in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110146.pdf) paper and directly generalize spreading models in the sense that if $(x^{k}_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}=(x^{j}_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ for all $k\neq j$, then $(v_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is the spreading model generated by this single sequence. However, asymptotic models need not be $1$-spreading in general and, in addition, sub-arrays of the form $(x^{k_{j}}_{i})_{i=1,j\in\mathbb{N}}^{\infty}$ need not generate asymptotic models of $X$ (these sub-arrays need not even be $M$-basic because sequences ``above the diagonal" in the original array need not be $M$-basic). Suppose we now impose the following restrictions on the array $(x^{k}_{i})_{i=1,k\in\mathbb{N}}^{\infty}$ that generates $(v_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ as an asymptotic model of $X$:

- The asymptotic model $(v_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is $1$-spreading
- Every sub-array of the form $(x^{k_{j}}_{i})_{i=1,j\in\mathbb{N}}^{\infty}$ is $M$-basic and generates an asymptotic model (clearly, $(v_{k_{i}})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ which is $1$-equivalent to the original asymptotic model $(v_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$)
- There is some $C>0$ such that, for every sub-array $(x^{k_{j}}_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$, the decreasing sequence $\epsilon_{n}\downarrow 0$ is bounded above by $C$.

It is easy to see that these hypotheses are satisfied if $(x^{k}_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}=(x^{j}_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ for all $k\neq j$. **My question is this:** is there a concrete example where these restrictions hold but where $(v_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is not a spreading model of $X$?

As a starting place, I know it is possible using block bases of some normalized $M$-basic sequence to construct an $M$-basic array $(x^{k}_{i})_{i=1,k\in\mathbb{N}}^{\infty}$ such that every sub-array $(x^{k_{j}}_{i})_{i=1,j\in\mathbb{N}}^{\infty}$ is $M$-basic. I think it is also possible to simultaneously $\frac{\epsilon_{n}}{2}$-stabilize all of these sub-arrays using a modified version of the usual Ramsey-theoretic diagonalization argument. If this is so, then the question boils down to whether or not it is possible for the asymptotic model in this case to be $1$-spreading.

Comment: I believe this and some of your older related questions are answered in [this Argyros-Motakis paper.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.10092)  They show, for instance, that you can have $c_0$ asymptotic model while all spreading models are equivalent to some $\ell_p$.

Comment: Dr. Sari, thank you for responding to this and my older related questions! I see that Theorem 8.2 (a) from the Argyros-Motakis paper yields, for every $\epsilon>0$, an asymptotic model generated by a block basic array that is $(1+\epsilon)$-equivalent to $c_{0}$. I am not seeing exactly how these arrays relate to the arrays in my original question, but perhaps more natural restrictions for the latter arrays are: (1) C-equivalent to a $1$-spreading sequence, (2) same as originally stated, and (3) same as originally stated. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: If the array has $c_0$ asymptotic model  then the subarrays as you described (you are deleting some rows, correct?) also has $c_0$ as. model. (Simply spread the scalar sequence $(\lambda_i)$.) Whenever i say the array has $c_0$ as. model i mean after refining it (passing subsequences in rows).I agree that in general subarrays a priori may not be $M$-basic but if it generates an unconditional as. model, then I think they are. Modifying (1) as you suggested might be more natural, I agree.

Comment: If by rows, you mean that I am deleting specific basic sequences (as opposed to a term from each sequence) from the array, then yes.